# Inserting variable into SQL query from Java

Tags: java, mysql

How do you insert variables into an SQL Query?

This is what I have so far ...

```
public String getBugList(int amount) {
    Connection con  = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT submitter, report FROM bugs_log ORDER BY id DESC limit ))
}
```

I'm trying to get "amount" bugs to list. So if I input 2, then only the top 2 will get listed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public String getBugList(int amount) {
    Connection con  = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    String query = "SELECT submitter, report FROM bugs_log ORDER BY id DESC limit ?";
    try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
        ps.setInt(1, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: While seemingly correct, I can't say I'm a fan of this answer because it doesn't use try-with-resources where that language construct fits perfectly (and the OP uses it).

Comment: @Vulcan My company was using Java 6 until like 2 weeks ago...we finally upgraded to Java 7 but let's just say I've been writing code which would compile when Jay Gosling was still a young man.

Answer (score 2):

Put a ? at the desired variable location. Then, from this API, call the set method for the variable type.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

In your case you want an int, so call `ps.setInt(1,x)`. If you want multiple variables, - or in SQL terms a "parameter" - , just use multiple `?`'s. The PreparedStatement setter methods requires the parameters index. The max index is equal to the amount of `?`'s you have in your query.