# Trying to understand how you insert variables into jdbc sql queries?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert a variable into an sql statement in java. I've read another post at [Inserting variable into SQL query from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508363/inserting-variable-into-sql-query-from-java) but I didn't really understand what they did.

```
   public static void searchordernumber(int inputnum) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM orderTable WHERE ordernumber=?";
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println("works");
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

How do I put the inputnum variable where the ? is?

Answer (score 2):

To bind a parameter into a `?` placeholder in a SQL statement use `PreparedStatment`. See [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) docs, it's more or less following:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM orderTable WHERE ordernumber = ?";
int orderNumber = 123;
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInt(1, orderNumber); 
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a PreparedStatement, as in:

```
public static void searchordernumber(int inputnum) {
  try {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM orderTable WHERE ordernumber = ?";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql));
    ps.setInt(1, inputnum); // here's the magic
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
      int id = rs.getInt(1); // assuming there's a column "id" of type INT
      System.out.println("id=" + id);
    }
    connection.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```